# Changing drive letter in NERDtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I started using NERDtree plugin on a a windows platform. I can't seem to find a way to change the drive letter. Going up all the way on the directory tree doesn't lead to the drive letter. Any ideas?
(Yes, I know, it's going to be a simple answer)

Comment: Feel free to erase this question

Comment: No. Why delete the question. It's good.

Comment: @amischiefr: who cares about google serps?

Comment: +1 exactly the question on my lips

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to go to your Z drive, for example, start it as:

```
:NERDTree Z:\
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use:

```
:NERDTree d:\
```

in the NERDTree window you will see it works. But now if you open(and edit) a file with NERDTree you will find it can not be saved, because the current working directory has not changed'; it is still in the old directory!

So if you want change the drive in NERDTree I advise you to perform the following 2 steps:

```
cd drive:\

:NERDTree .
```

where drive is the drive letter you want to change to, and . means change the NERDTree directory to the current working directory.

Now you can use NERDTree opening (or editing)the file in new directory now.

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can instead do `set autochdir` in your `.vimrc`, so that whenever you open a file (whether from NERDTree or otherwise), vim automatically does a `cd` to the path containing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not  **directly**  related, but if anyone finds themselves here from Google, ":e <location>" works in nvim-tree.

I'm putting this here because that's how I got here.