# Vim hide tear-off menu on Windows xp

Tags: windows, vim, editor

My problem is I'm trying to hide the `tear-off-menu` for `VIM` on Window XP(Sp3). I just don't like it. How can I do that. Please help.

Just as a suggestions I'm asking the below mentioned question -

I'm learning to use the `VIM` editor for Windows, mainly the GUI version. Then I was pointed to learn from this blog - [Vim Novice Tutorial Videos](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-novice-tutorial-videos/). Now the tutorials are good but there are practically no tutorials for VIM on windows. Can anyone point me to some windows tutorial for vim.

Another thing is that, I was trying to use the [`vimrc`](https://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-config) file of this user but was unable to setup plugins for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set guioptions-=t
```

in your _vimrc will hide the tear off menu items in the future.

Regarding the tutorials (Vim/GVim on Windows), no, they aren't usually divided between *Vim on Unix/Linux* and  *Vim on Windows*, Vim being rather similar on all of those. Some things differ (for example, the name of your vimrc file which is customary _vimrc on Windows, and .vimrc on the *nix boxes), but users usually pick those quickly and forget about them.

Regarding the vimrc file and the plugins found on that link, what is your directory structure? Where did you put vim runtime files and where did you put these configuration files in regards to vim's position? Could you tell what errors (problems) did you encounter?

Comment: @Idigas, Was wrong with plugin directory. Anyway installed `NERDTree`. One problem is even if I set to ignore case and type `:nerdtreetoggle` it can't find the plugin, I have to specifically type `NERDTreeToggle` to bring it up.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - Yes, but you can use the tab for autocompletion of names, can't you? If not, "set wildmode=list:longest" and "set wildmenu", then try again.

Comment: @Idigas, Excellent. Thanks mate. Could you possible tell me how to change the drive. I'm doing `:cd D:`, its going to `D:` but the folder and file list is not refreshed. Its still showing `C:` files

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - On windows, CD does not change drive. Just plain "D:" does. Now, from Vim's NERDTree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467447/changing-drive-letter-in-nerdtree

Comment: @Idigas, When I'm already inside NerdTree then how do I change the drive?

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - Oh, that ... uhmm, that - I have no idea. I don't use it so ... :/